# Simple Distribution Function

Tags: probability-theory

Given that you have a random variable $X$ and you know it's distribution is binomial, and its mass function: $\binom{k}{X}(\frac{1}{365})^X(\frac{364}{365})^{k-X}$, what is the distribution function?

I knew how to figure out the mass function, and I understand what a cumulative distribution functions do (add up the area under the function), but how to you write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity of typing, and generality, write $p$ for $1/365$, and therefore $1-p$ for $364/365$.

Suppose we repeat the experiment independently $k$ times. Let random variable $X$ be the number of "successes." Then the probability mass function of $X$ is given by
$$\Pr(X=x)=\binom{k}{x}p^x (1-p)^{k-x}.$$
Please note that in the it is **not** $X$, it is $x$.

For the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$, this is given by 
$$F_X(x)=\sum_{i\le x}\binom{k}{i}p^i (1-p)^{k-i}.$$

There is no pleasant simple form for $F_X(x)$. There are useful **approximations**, for example by the normal distribution. That would probably not be good in this case, since $p$ is too small. The Poisson approximation could be useful. Nowadays, there are good programs to calculate the cdf. So approximations are of diminishing practical importance.